# Python MySQL connector cursor prints -1... why?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm using the mysql.connector module. When I execute a query, it prints -1 to the screen, even when the query returns the values I wanted. What does the -1 mean? I can't find any mention of it in any documentation, and I'd appreciate an explanation or link. Thanks!

```
>>> dbcursor.execute(myquery)
-1
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) says _Returns an iterator when Multi is True_. It doesn't say anything about the return value in other cases, I expect you're supposed to ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would tell us that your `dbcursor` is a `SSCursor` or a `SSDictCursor`, we could tell you that this is normal behaviour: under the hood, these cursors work with `use_result()` instead of `store_result()`, and here the number of affected rows is only known at the end, after all rows have been retrieved.

Comment: I didn't realize there were different types of cursors; I just used db = mysql.connection.connect(...) and dbcursor = db.cursor(). Still, it's useful to know this is normal behavior, rather than an indicator of something going wrong.